# Google maps api url Fastest route

Tags: api, google-maps, url

The code below will give me an option of what route I wish to take but how can I select the "Fastest" or "shortest" route from the URL?

```
https://www.google.com.au/maps/dir/Adelaide+SA+Australia/Burnside+SA+Australia?nogmmr=1
```

Comment: I'm 99% sure that you can not do that. You can activate the traffic feature but still this feature is somehow not good yet. Google maps will always render the best possible paths based on their algorithms.

Comment: Is there a way to just select top option via url?

Comment: What are you referring to when you say top option?

Comment: which  top option do you want to select?

Comment: First avaliable route. In my example there are 3 I think I want the top one to be displayed setp by step

Comment: Have a look at here I believe this the best it gets concerning your problem, url:https://gearside.com/easily-link-to-locations-and-directions-using-the-new-google-maps/

Comment: Explain down vote as its a valid question

Comment: @eugensunic thats the site I found above from. Looks like its not possible

Comment: Yeap, I'm afraid I can't help on that. Maybe some expert can give his opinion and a answer which would lead you towards a semi - solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found a work around

```
import json, urllib
from urllib import urlencode
import googlemaps
start = "Bridgewater, Sa, Australia"
finish = "Stirling, SA, Australia"

url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?%s' % urlencode((
            ('origin', start),
            ('destination', finish)
 ))
ur = urllib.urlopen(url)
result = json.load(ur)

for i in range (0, len (result['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'])):
    j = result['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'][i]['html_instructions'] 
    print j
```

Google maps will go the fastest route by default.
The above trip has 2 ways side streets or highway. Highway was used as its fastest

Comment: Are you sure about the fact that google maps will go by the fastest route? Is there any doc or reference of the same? Also as per your code do you calculate the distance or duration parameters in the json response and then get the minimum of those values ?